# Sturm-Liouville and Gram-Schmidt

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, sturm-liouville

Going back through some old class notes, I found this statement that I haven't been able to prove or determine if it's false and only the result of bad note-taking.

**Statement:**
*Given arbitrary n-degree polynomials, if you Gram-Schmidt with respect to the Sturm-Liouville weight gives us orthogonal polynomials that are eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville differential equation.*

**Attempt:**
I do recall that solutions to Sturm-Liouville problems form a complete orthogonal basis and that they are unique, up to a constant. But all this just gives me the the orthogonalized functions can be written as a linear combination of the eigenfunctions that span a subspace of space span by all eigenfunctions.

Any hints forward (or against the above statement) are welcome.

Comment: That sounds like it might be right? Maybe try checking it in the setting of the Legendre polynomials to verify?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, that would seem to say that all Sturm-Liouville problems have polynomial solutions. Do you believe that?